# Error: Can't reconstruct data frame. x The `[` method for class <findFn/data.frame> must return a data frame with 1 column

Tags: r

I need a bit help here. I am new to R.
On running the below code in R studio

```
    library(sos)
library(htmlTable)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# Get auc functions
auc.search <- findFn("auc") 
auc.functions <- auc.search %>%
    filter(Function == "auc", Package != "pROC") %>%
    select(Package, Function, Description, Link)
rownames(auc.functions) <- auc.functions$Package
```

Error: Can't reconstruct data frame.
x The `[` method for class <findFn/data.frame> must return a data frame with 1 column.
i It returned a <findFn/data.frame> of 10 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object "auc.search" is an object with `class()` "findFn". That object has multiple attributes that makes it different from a dataframe.

```
class(auc.search)
## [1] "findFn"     "data.frame"
```

You should be able to apply functions for the dataframe by coercing the object:

```
auc.functions <- data.frame(auc.search) %>%
    filter(Function == "auc", Package != "pROC") %>%
    select(Package, Function, Description, Link)
```

Subsetting with this approach should also be useful:

```
auc.search[auc.search$Function == "auc"
           & auc.search$Package != "pROC",
           c("Function", "Package",  "Description", "Link")]
```